# assign userID as value and username as ng-model to a select tag

Tags: html, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

My question is probably easy, but I am having difficulties to solve it. I am developing an application using ASP.Net MVC and AngularJS. And I am using `select tag` to list users. I assigned to the `select tag` the same `ng-model` that I have assigned to `div` for real-time binding (user names).

My question is, when I change the item (user) in the `select tag` and save, I want to save using ID not username.

As you know, `ng-model` is equals `username` and I want it that way, but when it comes to saving the data, I want to use value and I want it the same as userID not name.

```
<div>{{supervisor}}</div>
<select ng-model="supervisor">
    <option ng-repeat="x in supervisors" ng-selected='supervisor == (x.supervisorfName+" "+x.supervisorlName)'>{{x.supervisorfName+" "+x.supervisorlName}}</option>
 </select>
<a href="javascript:void(0)" ng-click="updateUserSupervisor()"><i class="fa fa-floppy-o fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
```

The above `select tag` is listing users from database table. It has the same `ng-model` as the `div` in the top... When I click on the save icon below the `select tag`, I want to update the database table but not using `ng-model` because it is the name. Instead, I want to use `ID`.

So, how can I add ID in addition to `ng-model` in a `select tag`??

Below is the angularJS controller code that calls the database:

```
$http.get('/Home/GetSupervisor')
    .then(function (response) {
        $scope.supervisors = response.data;
    })
    .catch(function (e) {
        console.log("error", e);
        throw e;
    })
    .finally(function () {
        console.log("This finally block");
    });
```

And finally, below is the MVC code:

```
public JsonResult GetSupervisor()
    {
        var db = new scaleDBEntities();
        return this.Json((from userObj in db.Users
                          select new
                          {
                              supervisorId = userObj.Id,
                              supervisorfName = userObj.usrFirstName,
                              supervisorlName = userObj.usrLastName,                                  
                          })
                          , JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
                        );
    }
```

As requested, below is my angular controller:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('mainController', function ($scope, $http) {
$http.get('/Home/GetUser')
    .then(function (response) {
        $scope.users = response.data;
        $scope.itmNo = response.length;        

    })
    .catch(function (e) {
        console.log("error", e);
        throw e;
    })
    .finally(function () {
        console.log("This finally block");
    });


$http.get('/Home/GetSupervisor')
    .then(function (response) {
        $scope.supervisors = response.data;
    })
    .catch(function (e) {
        console.log("error", e);
        throw e;
    })
    .finally(function () {
        console.log("This finally block");
    });
```

});

Comment: How are you posting the data, Is it a normal form submit or are you posting your angular object to a web api ? Please show us the relevant parts(code) of your current implementation.

Comment: I have added some code. Hopefully this can help

Comment: I really need this. Hopefully someone can help me on this

Answer (score 0):

You can set your ng-model to be an object( which represent your user/supervisor entity) instead of just the name.

So add a new property to your scope called supervisor.

```
myApp.controller('mainController', function ($scope, $http) {

   $scope.supervisor=null;

  //your existing code goes here
};
```

Now in your view, you can use the name property to display the selected supervisor name.

```
<div>{{supervisor.supervisorfName}} {{supervisor.supervisorlName}}</div>

<select ng-options="option.supervisorfName for option in supervisors"
        ng-model="supervisor"></select>
```

When you have to save, you can get the id of the selected supervisor from the id property like `$scope.supervisor.supervisorId`

And to show both first name and last name in the option, you simply need to concatenate

```
<select ng-options="option.supervisorfName+' '
                                       +option.supervisorlName for option in supervisors"
        ng-model="supervisor"></select>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I will try this out and I will get back to you

Comment: I am sorry, I am new to this... Would you please tell me how I can add a new property in my scope? I mean to add it as an object

Comment: how does your angular controller looks like ? Can you post a jsbin sample ?

Comment: `$scope.supervisor.supervisorId` is not recognized in angular controller

Comment: It should work fine. [Here](http://jsbin.com/jalixanuco/edit?html,js,console,output) is a working sample. Compare it with your code which is broken and fix it.

Comment: Yes, it does work with this example. But it did not work with me. So, I am suspecting the json format that has been returned from my MVC controller. I am not sure, but this is so far the only thing that I can conclude.